# Preserving inner div width when outer div width is animated to 0px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hLzfr06j/3/

```
<div class="outer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Sed posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis,
        lacinia quis facilisis sed sapien. Mauris varius diam vitae arcu.
        Sed arcu lectus auctor vitae, consectetuer et venenatis eget velit.
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to animate outer div to `width: 0px;` so that the content of the inner div preserves it's width and is not pushed down during the animation as in the fiddle.

Edit: The overflowing part of the inner div content should be hidden during the animation.

Edit: So that the animation goes like this:

[image]

Comment: Something like this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/hLzfr06j/13/)

Comment: Not really, see the picture to the description.

Comment: why not use absolute position and when the new class is added onto the text, position it right by 100%, rather than shrink it

Comment: @jsg I updated the picture to be more descriptive. I think positioning to right would not make it shrink to the left like in the pic..? Create a fiddle thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the width of the inner div before you change the outer div's width:

```
function slide() {
    var currentWidth = $(".inner").width();
    $(".inner").width(currentWidth);
    $(".outer").addClass("collapsed");
}
function slideBack() {

    $(".outer").removeClass("collapsed");

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".inner").width("auto");
    }, 350);
}
```

On slide back, I also added a timeout equal to the transition duration so that it doesn't flicker while the outer div is still in the process of changing.

```
div.outer {
    padding: 0;//add
    overflow: hidden; //add

    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
    transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
}
```

You also need to add overflow property and make sure there is no padding to the outer div.

https://jsfiddle.net/reesewill/fb1sj7zz/